# Embed all resources/images into EXE file? VisualStudio VB WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am getting ready to sell a piece of software. When I compile the program, I get a "Resources" folder with all my images inside the folder. I do not want to have the end user have access to the image files. Is there a way to embed all the images into the .exe file or another way to make them inaccessible?

Comment: Use "Embedded Resource" for Build Action.

Comment: Use *Resource*, not *Embedded Resource* as Build Action.